# form no submit after check values (JS)

Tags: javascript

I have a question about the form I'm working on, I have a js script that checks if the data entered by the user is correct or not, it works well however if everything is ok the form does not send while I used the submit () function.

```js
  const form = document.getElementById("form");
  const title = document.getElementById("title");
  const subtitle = document.getElementById("subtitle");
  const lieu = document.getElementById("lieu");
  const date = document.getElementById("date");
  const file = document.getElementById("file");
  const file2 = document.getElementById("file2");
  const file3 = document.getElementById("file3");
  const description = document.getElementById("description");


  //Show input error message

  function showError(input, message) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    formControl.className = "form-control error";
    const small = formControl.querySelector("small");
    small.innerText = message;
  }

  //show success message

  function showSuccess(input) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    formControl.className = "form-control success";
  }

  //check required fields

  function checkRequired(inputArr) {
    inputArr.forEach(function(input) {
      if (input.value.trim() === "") {
        showError(input, `${getFieldName(input)} Filed is required`);
      } else {
        showSuccess(input);
      }
    });
  }

  //get field name
  function getFieldName(input) {
    return input.id.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.id.slice(1);
  }

  //check length

  function checkLength(input, min, max) {
    if (input.value.length < min) {
      showError(
        input,
        `${getFieldName(input)} must be atleast ${min} characters`
      );
    } else if (input.value.length > max) {
      showError(
        input,
        `${getFieldName(input)} must be less than ${max} characters`
      );
    } else {
      showSuccess(input);
    }
  }



  //Event listeners
  form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    let checkValue = checkRequired([title, subtitle, lieu, date, file, file2, file3, description]);
    let checkLengthTitle =  checkLength(title, 3, 45);
    let checkLengthDes = checkLength(description, 50, 800);

    if (checkValue && checkLengthTitle && checkLengthDes) {
      form.submit();
    } 
  });
```

Comment: None of your `check` functions returns a value, so `checkValue`, `checkLengthTitle` etc will all be undefined.

Answer (score -2):

```js
  const form = document.querySelector("#form");
  const title = document.querySelector("#title");
  const subtitle = document.querySelector("#subtitle");
  const lieu = document.querySelector("#lieu");
  const date = document.querySelector("#date");
  const file = document.querySelector("#file");
  const file2 = document.querySelector("#file2");
  const file3 = document.querySelector("#file3");
  const description = document.querySelector("#description");


  //Show input error message

  function showError(input, message) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    formControl.className = "form-control error";
    const small = formControl.querySelector("small");
    small.innerText = message;
  }

  //show success message

  function showSuccess(input) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    formControl.className = "form-control success";
  }

  //check required fields

  function checkRequired(inputArr) {
    var hasError =  false;
    inputArr.forEach(function(input) {
      if (input.hasAttribute('required') && input.values.length == 0 ) {
          hasError = true;
        showError(input, `${getFieldName(input)} Filed is required`);
      } else {
        showSuccess(input);
      }
    });
    return !hasError;
  }

  //get field name
  function getFieldName(input) {
    return input.id.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.id.slice(1);
  }

  //check length

  function checkLength(input, min, max) {
      var hasError = false
    if (input.value.length < min) {
                hasError = true

      showError(
        input,
        `${getFieldName(input)} must be atleast ${min} characters`
      );
    } else if (input.value.length > max) {
        hasError = true
      showError(
        input,
        `${getFieldName(input)} must be less than ${max} characters`
      );
    } else {
      showSuccess(input);
    }

    return !hasError;
  }
 //Event listeners
  form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    let checkValue = checkRequired([title, subtitle, lieu, date, file, file2, file3, description]);
    let checkLengthTitle =  checkLength(title, 3, 45);
    let checkLengthDes = checkLength(description, 50, 800);

    if (checkValue && checkLengthTitle && checkLengthDes) {
      form.submit();
    } 
  });
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not my question, the value checking functions are correct, what doesn't work is the form.submit ()

Comment: I just made the appropriate modifications, it was just your method return void

Comment: You should not just post code. You should clearly explain what the problem was, why it caused the issue, and what you changed and why that fixes it.

Comment: Ok the problem is simple your methods managed to detect errors but they do not return anything so that when checking to be able to submit the form your variables are undefined